# Parallel circuit: probability of failure

Tags: probability, self-study

a) Relays used in the construction of electric circuits function properly with probability .9. Assuming that the circuits operate independently, what is the probability that current will flow when the relays are activated?

[image]

b) If we know that current is flowing, what is the
probability that switches 1 and 4 are functioning properly?

---

I denote $F_1$ the event switch 1 fails and $W_1$ the event switch 1 works and use the subscript $_S$ for the whole system and $1\leq i\neq j\neq k\neq l\leq4$ . Part a) is easy: this is $1-P(F_S)$ and $$P(F_S)=P(F_S|F_iF_jW_kW_l)P(F_iF_jW_kW_l)+P(F_S|F_iF_jF_kW_l)P(F_iF_jF_kW_l)+P(F_S|F_iF_jF_kF_l)P(F_iF_jF_kF_l)\\
=4.1^2.9^2+4*.1^3*.9+1^4=.9639$$

(which, the back pages of the book confirms, is the correct answer). Now, for part b) I think there are 7 combinations that allow the current to flow:

$$\{1:W_2W_4F_1F_3\}\\
\{2:W_1W_3F_2F_4\}\\
\{3:W_1W_2W_3F_4\}\\
\{4:W_1W_2W_4F_3\}\\
\{5:W_1W_3W_4F_2\}\\
\{6:W_2W_3W_4F_1\}\\
\{7:W_1W_2W_3W_4\}$$

Of these only combination 7,5 and 4 have $W_1W_4$ in them so that

$$P(W_1W_4??|F_S)=\frac{2*.1*.9^3+.9^4}{.9639}\approx.831$$

And when I do a classical approach using the Bayes formula I get to the same number. However the book says the correct answer is $.916$.

I must add, I have done 40 exercises off this book already and it would be the first time one of the answers is incorrect. The book is very well edited. Therefore my guess is that I misunderstand the question.

So, here is my question: what is my mistake?

Comment: Could be a mistake in interpretation (more likely a poorly worded question). If you calculate the probability that switch 1 is working given that current is flowing you will find it is .916. Same thing if you calculate the probability that switch 4 is working. For switch 1, this corresponds to the combinations 2, 3, 4, 5, and 7. For switch 4: 1,4,5,6,7.

Comment: @DaltonHance: Thanks That could be expended into an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same answer, using a probability tree.

A simulation supports it, as in this `R` example.

```R
N <- 1e6
set.seed(17)
x <- matrix(runif(4*N) < 0.9, nrow=4)
flows <- (x[1,] & x[3,]) | (x[2,] & x[4,])
on.1.4 <- x[1,] & x[4,]

mean(flows) # Should approximate 0.9639
sum(flows & on.1.4) / sum(flows)
```

The output from these million iterations (in which 963,956 evidenced a flow) is

```
[1] 0.963956
[1] 0.8320089
```

The first number is comfortably close to $0.9639$ while the other clearly shows $0.832$ is plausible while $0.916$ is not.  The standard error in the second calculation will be approximately

$$\sqrt{0.832(1-0.832)/963956} \approx 0.00019,$$

showing the simulated estimate of $0.8320089$ is within $0.4$ standard errors of $0.9^3(1 + 2(0.1)) \approx 0.83193$.

---

Because of the special nature of the probabilities involved, we can also exhaustively enumerate the possibilities, as in this code:

```R
p <- c(rep(1,9), 0)
X <- as.matrix(expand.grid(G1=p, G2=p, G3=p, G4=p))
flows <- (X[,1] & X[,3]) | (X[,2] & X[,4])
on <- X[,1] & X[,4]

sum(flows & on)
sum(flows)
```

The output shows the *completely accurate* answer is $8019/9639 = 0.8319328\cdots$.

---

Of course, the computer can easily enumerate all $16$ possibilities in the probability tree.  But you and I already did that manually, with the same results.

Comment: Thank you for having taken the time to draft this authoritative answer. For reference the book is Dennis D. Wackerly, William Mendenhall, Richard L. Scheaffer: Mathematical Statistics with Applications and it is exercise 2.165.

Comment: Maybe this question should be made a CW?

Comment: Why?  I cannot see any characteristic that would suggest it should be so.

Comment: I have a hard time deciding what the correct answer should be~.  I originally understood the question as you did but now I think both interpretation of the question make sense.

Comment: When issues of interpretation come up, the first place to refer is the text of the question itself.  Yours asks "what is my mistake"? That has a unique correct answer: you didn't make one. That is demonstrated by showing that you correctly answered the question as stated.  We could go further and read another question into your post: "what is the book's mistake"?  That indeed has several plausible answers (and they are interesting to consider): it could have erred in asking the question or in the answer.  Identifying the possible errors is useful, *but that is not what you asked for.*

Comment: @whuber At the risk of going too meta, there are many ways a reader could interpret "what is my mistake?" It is not clear from OP text that interpreting ambiguity errors in the source material is out of bounds. Given that this entire site's focus is on the precise formulation and answering of statistical questions, this is an excellent example of the dire importance of the specific wording of questions. In my opinion, the best statistical consultants are not those with the fanciest math, but those who can interpret a client's real question from a vague or ambiguous initial formulation.

Comment: @whuber, I should probably revise my final sentence above. I realize after rereading it that it could come across as veiled insult. I sincerely did *not* mean to convey anything of the sort. Oh boy, we've really gone meta here, but please do not let me be misunderstood. I simply meant to point out that language is at the heart of statistical practice and it is interesting to see that emphasized in a simple textbook example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just that the second part of the problem is a poorly worded question. Instead lets rewrite it as two questions: "If we know that current is flowing, what is the probability that switch 1 is functioning properly? If we know that current is flowing, what is the probability that switch 4 is functioning properly?"

You can then solve using your same approach and using the 7 combinations you've outlined. For switch 1, the first of our two new questions corresponds to the combinations 2, 3, 4, 5, and 7. For switch 4: 1,4,5,6,7.

Both of these sets of combinations have the same probability:

$$Pr(W_1???|F_S) = Pr(W_4???|F_S) = \frac{.9^2*.1^2 + 3*.1*.9^3 + .9^4}{.9639} \approx 0.916 $$

I've got the same book on my shelf. Maybe they'll fix it in the eighth edition.

Comment: Thanks for having taken the time to offer this interpretation.